# How to change the default shell for a vsphere.local user on a VMware VCSA server?

Tags: linux, shell, vmware, photonos

How to change the default shell for a `vsphere.local` user on a VMware VCSA 8 server (Photon OS/Linux 3.0) ?

I tried the `chsh` command but it does not work for a `vsphere.local` user :

```shell
PS C:\> ssh firstname.lastname@vsphere.local@MyVenter

VMware vCenter Server 8.0.1.00300

Type: vCenter Server with an embedded Platform Services Controller

Password:
Last login: Thu Jan  4 15:29:16 2024 from X.Y.Z.T
Connected to service

    * List APIs: "help api list"
    * List Plugins: "help pi list"
    * Launch BASH: "shell"

Command> shell
Shell is disabled.
Command> shell.set --enabled true
Command> shell
    ---------- !!!! WARNING WARNING WARNING !!!! ----------

Your use of "pi shell" has been logged!

The "pi shell" is intended for advanced troubleshooting operations and while
supported in this release, is a deprecated interface, and may be removed in a
future version of the product.  For alternative commands, exit the "pi shell"
and run the "help" command.

The "pi shell" command launches a root bash shell.  Commands within the shell
are not audited, and improper use of this command can severely harm the
system.

Help us improve the product!  If your scenario requires "pi shell," please
submit a Service Request, or post your scenario to the
https://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/vcenter/vc forum and add
"appliance" tag.

sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$ vpxd -v
VMware VirtualCenter 8.0.1 build-22088981
sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$ echo $(source /etc/os-release;echo "$PRETTY_NAME $VERSION")
VMware Photon OS/Linux 3.0
sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$ chsh -s /bin/bash
Password:
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$ chsh -s /bin/bash $USER
chsh: user 'firstname.lastname@vsphere.local' does not exist
sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$
```

EDIT0:

```shell
sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$ echo $USER
firstname.lastname@vsphere.local
sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$ chsh -s /bin/bash $USER@$HOSTNAME
chsh: user 'firstname.lastname@vsphere.local@MyVenter' does not exist
sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$ chsh -s /bin/bash firstname.lastname@$HOSTNAME
chsh: user 'firstname.lastname@MyVenter' does not exist
sso-user@MyVenter [ ~ ]$
```

EDIT1:

```shell
$ echo $USER
firstname.lastname@vsphere.local
$ echo $LOGNAME
firstname.lastname@vsphere.local
$ whoami
sso-user
$ hostname
MyVenter
$
```

EDIT2:

```shell
$ id $USER@$HOSTNAME
id: ‘firstname.lastname@vsphere.local@MyVenter’: no such user
$ id $USER
id: ‘firstname.lastname@vsphere.local’: no such user
$ ldapwhoami
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
        additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_65536))
$
```

Comment: Does your VSphere instance have another name other than `vsphere.local`? I mean I can tell it does because the user actually belongs to MyVenter.  Seems like you need to specifiy that the user is NOT $USER@vsphere.local but $USER@MyVenter assuming that `sso-user` is indeed `firstname.lastname`

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, my answer is in EDIT0.

Comment: Your edit adds even more confusion. Does the user firstname.lastname@MyVenter actually exist?

Comment: What’s the output of “whoami” and “hostname”?

Comment: @Ramhound See my EDIT1.

Comment: You’re attempting to use a user that doesn’t exist. I asked awhile ago if sso-user and firstname.lastname was the same user, the last output, makes it clear that isn’t the case.  So create the user on the machine.

Comment: @Ramhound You're right, the `whoami` output makes it clear. And it also seems that all the remote users from the `vsphere.local` "domain" land onto the local `sso-user`.

Comment: So you should be able to authenticate as `sso-user@MyVenter` because in my experience if you provide the username@hostname it will work but you I am not familar with authentication with VCSA 8 only earlier versions. I just recognize the authentication error you receive is likely correct. I don't suppose `chsh -s /bin/bash firstname.lastname@vsphere.local@MyVenter` works? I do understand you want to go from pi shell (the applicance shell) to BASH shell, right?

Comment: @Ramhound My EDIT0 shows that `firstname.lastname@vsphere.local@MyVenter` does not exist. BTW : It also seems the authentification mecanism is the same on a VCSA 7 server. Yes I want to switch to bash but only for my `firstname.lastname@vsphere.local` user not for `sso-user@MyVenter`.